# Date only comparison using "isBefore" in Java Joda Time

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

Is there a way to have only dates compared for **DateTime** object with **isBefore** function?

For ex.,

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(Long.parseLong(<someInput>));
DateTime end   = new DateTime(Long.parseLong(<someInput>));
```

Now when I do,

```
while (start.isBefore(end)) { 
   // add start date to the list
   start = start.plusDays(1);
}
```

This results in inconsistent behavior (for my scenario) as it is taking into consideration time as well whereas what I want is to have just the dates compared using isBefore. Is there a way I can do that?

Please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to compare dates only you probably want to use the `LocalDate` class, rather than a `DateTime`.

The JodaTime docs are pretty good: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wanted to store DateTime inside the loop so instead of converting DateTime to LocalDate and then convert LocalDate back to DateTime, I think it's better idea to use DateFormatter.

Comment: Just make sure you don't have any weird behaviour when entering/leaving daylight savings time! Dates and times are often trickier than they first appear...

Comment: I just re-evaluated the use cases for my application and looks like I would be better off using LocalDate. Thanks!

Comment: @TimGage Just for a clarification. Your comment on use the `LocalDate` rather than a `DateTime`. Is there any issue or any overhead using `DateTime`..?

Comment: No. the only reason I suggested using `LocalDate` was that the question specifically asked about comparing date components. Using `DateTime` is fine, but it's modelling a different concept. It's important to select the right one for your needs.

Answer (score 9):

Another strategy is to format it.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
DateTime newStart = df.parse(start);
DateTime newEnd = df.parse(end);

while (newStart.isBefore(newEnd)) { 
  // add start date to the list
  newStart = newStart.plusDays(1);
}
```

Comment: This is most close to what I want. Thanks much for the suggestion!

Comment: Try df.parse(start.toString());

Answer (score 1):

Switch to using LocalDate rather than DateTime.  The concept in JodaTime is a 'partial' (see the ReadablePartial interface).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wanted to store DateTime format only inside the loop. So I think I will stick with what George suggested below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is quite an old question but worth adding an answer! Joda-time is not preferred these days considering we have wonderful support in Java 8 for date-time operations. If you still have to use joda-time then use the `compareTo` method in `LocalDate` class.

> Compares this partial with another returning an integer indicating the
>   order. The fields are compared in order, from largest to smallest. The
>   first field that is non-equal is used to determine the result.
>
> The specified object must be a partial instance whose field types
>   match those of this partial.

Official Java-doc can be found [here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#compareTo(org.joda.time.ReadablePartial)).

Answer (score 0):

You could set the time of the `DateTime` to zero (which means midnight) after parsing:

```
// withTime sets hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds
DateTime start = new DateTime(Long.parseLong(<someInput>)).withTime(0, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime end   = new DateTime(Long.parseLong(<someInput>)).withTime(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Or use one of the other Joda Time classes; there's much more than `DateTime`! If you're dealing with dates only, you'll probably want to use `LocalDate` instead of `DateTime`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! After looking more closely to my application, I think I will change it to LocalDate instead of DateTime. Thanks!

Comment: Setting the time to midnight will not work if the time-zone has daylight savings gaps that include midnight. Calling `dayOfMonth().roundFloorCopy()` handles the edge case.